# Scan open port with netcat

Tags: linux, netcat

I'm just wrapping my head around the utility [netcat](https://manpages.debian.org/stretch/netcat-traditional/nc.1.en.html). So for test purpose I install Apache on my Linux OS and verified Apache runs by accessing the localhost url in my browser.

I want to test if the port 8080 was open on my machine by using netcat. I typed `nc -z localhost 8080` into the console but nothing shows in return. Apache is running so the port 8080 is open. I don't understand why nothing is showing ?

Also if I try to scan a range of ports using `nc -z localhost 1-9999` I also have nothing in return. Does it mean that no port is opened on my machine ?

Comment: Fastest way to check for open TCP ports on your own machine is ```ss -lt```.

Comment: thanks for your shorthand but it does not answer my questions

Answer (score 0):

I do not know why you would expect output. From the man page:

> > -z Specifies that nc should just scan for listening daemons, without sending any data to them.

What happens if you connect to an http-server without sending any data? You get no response. Compare this with the normal `cat`:

```
ljm@verlaine[~]$ touch this
ljm@verlaine[~]$ cat this
ljm@verlaine[~]$ cat that
cat: that: No such file or directory
```

`this` is an empty file. So, for `cat this` you get no answer. Not a message "hey I found this; but it is empty", but just the content of `this`. It works the same way with `nc`.

As an example, `pi` listens to port 80 on my network.

```
ljm@verlaine[~]$ nc -z pi 80
ljm@verlaine[~]$ nc -z pi 83
pi.home [192.168.178.2] 83 (mit-ml-dev) : Connection refused
ljm@verlaine[~]$  echo -n "GET / HTTP/1.0\r\n\r\n" | nc pi 80
HTTP/1.1 404 Not found
Content-Type: text/plain
Content-length: 11

Not found
```

So, the first `nc -z pi 80` connects to port 80 (which succeeds) sends nothing and does not get a reply.

The second `nc -z pi 83` You get a message from `nc` that explains what is wrong.

The third `nc` sends some data to the webserver and gets an answer (a 404, but that is irrelevant)

Comment: I don't understant. Ok you don't send data but when using nc -z shouldn't you have a response that say : hey the port 8080 is open ?

Comment: No, `nc` just gives the data it gets from the connection, which is nothing. If you want a confirmation of which ports are open, use `nmap`. Added the equivalent of `cat`; hope that makes it a bit clearer.

Answer (score 0):

> I don't understand why nothing is showing

In my Kubuntu I have the OpenBSD implementation of `nc`. Its manual states [emphasis mine]:

> It may be useful to know which ports are open and running services on a target machine.  The `-z` flag can be used to tell `nc` to report open ports, rather than initiate a connection. **Usually it's useful to turn on verbose output to stderr by use this option in conjunction with `-v` option.**

So try `nc -zv localhost 8080` or `nc -zv localhost 1-9999`.

I noticed I can test a *single* port by examining the exit status. Open port makes `nc` return `0`; failed connection makes `nc` return `1`. This approach works with or without `-v`.

In general, while testing ports this way, it's good to set a reasonably short timeout (e.g. `-w 7`) to avoid long delay when the scanned machine is completely silent.